# Enabling pysys tests being recorded

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to set up some automated testing based on the pysys framework.

The tests are running fine, and I have also added JUnitXMLResultsWriter based on samples shown in my project file.
However the recording is not activated for some reason.

I have located the variable record in BaseRunner, which when being set directly to True then works as expected, but this is properly not the intention.

Hence my questions is what should be in setup in order to activate recording of my testcases?

Kind Regards Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You enable recording from the pysys.py run launcher using the -r option i.e. "pysys.py run -r". This will then record the output based on the result writers configured in the .pysysproject file. For a full list of options use the -h option to the pysys.py launcher on the run target, i.e.

```
C:\dev>pysys.py run -h

PySys System Test Framework (version 0.9.2): Console run test helper

Usage: pysys.py run [option]* [tests]*
   where [option] includes;
       -h | --help                 print this message
       -r | --record               record the test results in the working directory
       -p | --purge                purge the output subdirectory on test pass
       -v | --verbosity STRING     set the verbosity level (CRIT, WARN, INFO, DEBUG)
       -a | --type      STRING     set the test type to run (auto or manual, default is both)
       -t | --trace     STRING     set the requirement id for the test run
       -i | --include   STRING     set the test groups to include (can be specified multiple times)
       -e | --exclude   STRING     set the test groups to exclude (can be specified multiple times)
       -c | --cycle     INT        set the the number of cycles to run the tests
       -o | --outdir    STRING     set the name of the test output subdirectory
       -m | --mode      STRING     set the user defined mode to run the tests
       -n | --threads   INT        set the number of worker threads to run the tests (defaults to 1).
                                   A value of 0 sets to the number of available CPUs
       -X               KEY=VALUE  set user defined options to be passed through to the test and
                                   runner classes. The left hand side string is the data attribute
                                   to set, the right hand side string the value (True of not specified)
```